# Increase height of keyboard popup in android

Tags: android, popup, android-softkeyboard

I have a sample keyboard with popup for symbols like this:[image: keyboard popup]

My keyboard xml:

```
....

    <Row>
    <Key android:codes="49" android:keyLabel="@string/letters_for_1q"  
            android:horizontalGap="3%p"
            android:verticalGap="1%p"
            android:popupCharacters="@string/alternates_for_1"
            android:popupKeyboard="@xml/popup_template"
            />

....
```

and popup_template

```
<Keyboard xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:keyWidth="10%p"
android:horizontalGap="0px"
android:verticalGap="0px"
android:keyHeight="@dimen/key_height">
</Keyboard>
```

I need that the popup don't extend the area of the keys.

i tried with popup layout without success.

could anyone help me with this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i have tried changing the keyWidth which works well

```
android:keyWidth="20dp"
```

in addition you can change text size in KeyboardView

```
android:keyTextSize="20sp"
```